# scrolling lightbox gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a scrolling a gallery that [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65gyV.png), I need to add an option that on click on one of the pictures, the clicked picture will cover 100% height and width of the screen, and the scrollbar will still appear under the picture in order to move to the next or the previous pictures that also will be in size of 100% of the screen.

It should [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnvQv.png).

This is the gallery that on the first example:

```js
$('.imageWrapper img').click(function() {
  $('.scrolls img').css({
   'width': '100%',
   'height': '100%'

 });

   $('.footerclass').css({
   'display': 'none'

 });
 });
```

```css
.wrapper {
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
 }
 
.scrolls { 
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
} 

.scrolls img { 
width: 275px;
cursor: pointer;
display:inline-block;
display:inline;
margin-right: -5px;
vertical-align:top;
}

.imageWrapper {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 120px;
}
    
.imageWrapper img {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper" id="column">
  <div class="scrolls">
    <div class="imageWrapper">
      <img src="images/01.jpg" />
      <a href="" class="cornerLink">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
      <img src="images/01.jpg" />
      <a href="" class="cornerLink">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">       
      <img src="images/01.jpg" />
      <a href="" class="cornerLink">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
      <img src="images/01.jpg" />
      <a href="" class="cornerLink">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
      <img src="images/01.jpg" />
      <a href="" class="cornerLink">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="imageWrapper">
      <img src="images/01.jpg" />
      <a href="" class="cornerLink">Link</a>
    </div>
      <?php include 'footer.php';?>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I tried to add a JS that will change the size of all pictures to 100% height and width on click on one the picture. You could see that in the snippet.

My problem is how to display the specific picture that the user clicked on in 100% and still to have an option to scroll to previous or next pictures.

Comment: You say you want the image to cover 100% heigh and 100% width. Do you want it to stretch, or to lose part of the image?

Comment: I want it to stretch

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the specific picture that the user clicked then I would suggest using `$(this).css()` selector instead of `$(.scrolls img).css()` to point more accurately to the image you're looking to render 100%.

Comment: Ok, that should help, but how can I set that all the other picture will also 100% in order that the user will be able to scroll  to the other pictures?

Comment: I'm not sure. It might be easier to just use a library like [lightgallery.js](https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightgallery.js/) to take care of that option for you?

Comment: I need that the scroll option will be available after clicking on picture